# How to interpolate values in non-rectangular coordinates using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, coordinate-transformation

I need to make compensation of values in my optical system using Python. I've measured the dependency of my compensation params in the corners of my table and I want to interpolate such value there linearly, but a map is not a rectangle.
Example:

```
# Corners coordinates:
a_real = (45, 45) 
a_coeff = (333, 223)

b_real = (-45, -45)
b_coeff = (325, 243)

c_real = (-45, 45)
c_coeff = (339, 244)

d_real = (45, -45)
d_coeff = (319, 228)
```

Let's say, I want to know compensation coefficients in points (40, 40), or (0, 0).
[image]

1. How this can be done? I'm looking at scipy.interpolate.interp2d but I'm not sure that it is my case
2. What if I want to add more points, defining my grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with 2D *unstructured* points, so you could use, for instance, the SciPy's [`interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) function.

I would suggest the following solution. I have rearranged your data in a more convenient way. You can add all the points you want to the `points` NumPy array.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

points = np.array([[333, 223], [325, 243], [339, 244], [319, 228]])

values_a = np.array([45, -45, -45, 45])
values_b = np.array([45, -45, 45, -45])
new_value_a = griddata(points, values_a, (325, 232), method="nearest")
new_value_b = griddata(points, values_b, (325, 232), method="nearest")
```

The code allows you to compute the two values for a new point having coordinates `(325, 232)`. If the new point lies outside the convex hull defined by your points, then you need to set the value of the `fill_value` parameter (unless you are using the `nearest` method as explained in the documentation).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I've looking for!